# Alternative for recursive aggregate queries not supported in sqlite3

Tags: recursion, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I would like to perform a SQL computation of a system evolving in time as

```
v <- v + a (*) v
```

where `v` is a vector of `N` components (`N >> 10`), `a` is an `N`-by-`N` matrix, fairly sparse, `(*)` denotes matrix multiplication, and the evolution is recursively computed as a sequence of timesteps, with each step using the previous value of `v`. `a` changes with time as an external factor, but it is sufficient for this question to assume `a` is constant.

I could do this recursion loop in an imperative language, but the underlying data was kind of messy and SQL was brilliant for normalising. It would be kind of neat to just finish the job in one language.

I found that matrix multiplication is fine. Recursion is fine too, as of sqlite 3.8. But matrix multiplication inside a recursion loop does not appear to be possible. Here is my progress so far (also at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ed521/1 ):

```
-- Example vector v
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS coords;
CREATE TABLE coords( row INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, val FLOAT );
INSERT INTO coords
VALUES
(1, 0.0 ),
(2, 1.0 );

-- Example matrix a
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS matrix;
CREATE TABLE matrix( row INTEGER, col INTEGER, val FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY( row, col ) );
INSERT INTO matrix
VALUES
( 1, 1, 0.0 ),
( 1, 2, 0.03 ),
( 2, 1, -0.03 ),
( 2, 2, 0.0 );

-- The timestep equation can also be expressed: v <- ( I + a ) (*) v, where the                
-- identity matrix I is first added to a.                                                      
UPDATE matrix
SET val = val + 1.0
WHERE row == col;

-- Matrix multiply to evaluate the first step.                                                 
SELECT a.row AS row, SUM( a.val*v.val ) AS val
FROM coords v
JOIN matrix a
ON a.col == v.row
GROUP BY a.row;
```

Here is where the problem arises. I can't see how to do a matrix multiply without a 
`GROUP BY` (aggregation) operation, but Sqlite3 specifically does not permit aggregation inside of a recursion loop:

```
-- Recursive matrix multiply to evaluate a sequences of steps.                                 
WITH RECURSIVE trajectory( row, val ) AS
(
        SELECT row, val
        FROM coords

        UNION ALL

        SELECT a.row AS row, SUM( a.val*v.val ) AS val
        FROM trajectory v       -- recursive sequence of steps                               
        --FROM coords v           -- non-recursive first step only                               
        JOIN matrix a
        ON a.col == v.row
        GROUP BY a.row
        LIMIT 50
)
SELECT *
FROM trajectory;
```

Returns

```
Error: recursive aggregate queries not supported
```

No doubt the designers had some clear reason for excluding it! I am surprised that JOINs are allowed but GROUP BYs are not. I am not sure what my alternatives are, though.

I've found a few other recursion examples but they all seem to have carefully selected problems for which aggregation or self-joins inside the loop are not required. In the docs( https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html ) an example query walks a tree recursively, and performs an `avg()` on the output. This is subtly different: the aggregation happens outside the loop, and tree-walking uses `JOIN`s but no aggregation inside the recursion loop. That problem proceeds only because the recursion does not depend on the aggregations, as it does in this problem.

Another example, the Fibonacci generator is an example of an `N = 2` linear dynamical system, but with `N = 2` the implementations can just hard-code the two values and the matrix multiply directly into the query, so no aggregating `SUM()` is needed. More generally with `N >> 10` it is not feasible to go down this path.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Version is SQLite 3.16.2.

Comment: Postgres 9.6 recursive CTEs have the same restriction.

Comment: I could not find any solution in sqlite and migrated the project to postgres to use RETURN QUERY inside a WHILE loop. It works well.